# java 7 : response.flushBuffer(); does not Download csv in browser

Tags: java, csv, spring-mvc, sap-commerce-cloud, opencsv

I have a csv Media file , I am trying to read this csv line by line and need to Download in the browser.

`response.flushBuffer();` does not seem to Start the Download. No errors observed.
I can see the complete data in the Browser response tab under Network and is in correct format. Just not able to flush it.

```java
final MediaModel media = mediaService.getMedia(catalogVersionModelHeader, mediaIdentifier);
        final Collection<File> filesHeader = mediaService.getFiles(media);

        final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filesHeader.iterator().next()));
        String line = "";
        final CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(getOutputWriter());
        final Map<Integer, String> data = new HashMap<>();
        int counter = 0;
        try {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                data.put(new Integer(counter), line);
                csvWriter.write(data);
            }
            counter++;
        } catch (final IOException ioException) {
            LOG.error(ioException);
        }

        csvWriter.close();
        response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + "Report.csv" + "\"");
        response.getOutputStream().write(getBytes(csvWriter));
        response.flushBuffer();

        }
    public byte[] getBytes(final CSVWriter csvWriter) {
        final StringWriter stringWriter = threadLocal.get();
        return stringWriter.getBuffer().toString().getBytes();
    }

    public Writer getOutputWriter() {
        final StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        threadLocal.set(writer);
        return writer;
    }
```

No Errors Observed.

Comment: What is `getWriter()`? You need to close the writer or stream.

Comment: @user207421 I don't see getWriter() anywhere.

Comment: My mistake, I meant `getOutputWriter()`. Where is it? What does it do?

Answer (score 2):

You have to close the `csvWriter` after you have written it to the `OutputStream` like this -

```
    ....
    ....
    response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + "Report.csv" + "\"");
    response.getOutputStream().write(getBytes(csvWriter));
    csvWriter.close();
    response.flushBuffer();
```

You CSV file content is not written to the `OutputStream` cause you are closing it before writing it to the `OutputStream`. Try just changing the order of closing `csvWriter`.